# why ncol option does not work in my facet_grid in R

Tags: r, facet, r-grid

I am trying to learn ggplot with facet. here is the codes works in Rstudio

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()

  # With one variable
p + facet_grid(. ~ cyl)
```

however, it shows error for ncol after I added ncol=2 :

```
    p + facet_grid( ~ cyl,ncol=2)

Error in facet_grid(~cyl, ncol = 2) : unused argument (ncol = 2)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
#use facet_wrap
p + facet_wrap( ~ cyl, ncol = 2)
```